# Is the python google-cloud-datastore package thread safe?

Tags: python, google-cloud-datastore

For a multithreaded Python program, do I create a separate google.cloud.datastore.Client instance for each thread, or can I use one shared across threads? Are there any thread safety concerns using google.cloud.datastore library?

Comment: Most things in Python are thread-safe, because unless the authors have gone to the trouble of managing the GIL themselves, there will be no concurrent execution of code from their library.

Comment: No, things are not thread-safe by default. Anything that uses mutable global variables in a module has a big risk of concurrency/safety issues unless they use thread-safe primitives.

Answer (score 3):

There are two confusingly-named projects (which you clarify, but I'm clarifying for other readers)

If you're asking about `googledatastore` (aka [google-cloud-datastore github repo](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-datastore) and [googledatastore package](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/googledatastore), then it appears to be threadsafe as of v1beta2-rev1-2.1.0: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-datastore/blob/master/RELEASE_NOTES.md

If you're asking about `google.cloud.datastore` (aka [google-cloud-python github repo](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-python) and [google-cloud-python package](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/google-cloud-datastore)), the answer is "[they think so](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-python/issues/3272), and any bugs to the contrary should be reported".